# AS3 - Pinch to Zoom Gesture for Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, gesture

I'm creating a tool which allows representatives to select the best product for our customers. There has been some demand to use this tool on a mobile device. I would like to give users the option to pinch-to-zoom in order to use the device more appropriately on small devices.

Due to the nature of the tool, I cannot put the contents of the tool into a movie clip and pinch-to-zoom that movie clip. My search for a working AS3 code to pinch-to-zoom the stage (and therefore the contents on the stage) has come up empty.

I did find this code on Stack Overflow:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom); 
function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
  stage.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
  stage.scaleY *= e.scaleY; 
}
```

This returns the following error when testing it through Adobe Animate:

```
Error: Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.display::Stage/set scaleX()
    at Beta04_fla::MainTimeline/onZoom()[Beta04_fla.MainTimeline::frame501:5]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/simulationSendGestureEvent()
    at runtime::SimulatedContentPlayer/clientSocketDataHandler()
```

Can anyone provide working code or advice on how to fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of scaling the stage, scale the document class (Main Timeline).  So: `this.scaleX *= e.scaleX;`

Comment: This worked! I'm certainly an amateur at coding, but even so, I feel stupid to have missed this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Stop scaling stage, its not a right way

move your contents to a child movieclip rather than stage, then scale or just use a bitmap:

You have to make a magnification instead.
you should at first make a snap shot of your stage, 
Means draw whole of stage or just wanted area of stage, to a bitmap object with your own transform matrix (matrix.scale(2,2)), then cut it off to your favorite size and simply prefer it to your clients as a new temporary movieclip.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(-50,-50); // moves your stage under magnifier
matrix.scale(3,3); // magnification
bitmapData.draw(stage, matrix);

// And to actually see it 
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
this.addChild(bitmap);
```

[image]

**also if want smooth animated zoom, you can update your bitmap with a step variable in your event listener which affects matrix changes according to distance between fingers, instead of static zoom in my code**

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but as I stated, putting the tool into a movie clip was problematic. @BadFeelingAboutThis provided an answer above which worked, though your answer may also work. Thank you again for your response.